# Does Neo4j have cost-effective way to store binary number data of node property?

Tags: string, neo4j, binary, cypher

For example, I have the data format of Neo4j node property like `'000110011010'` which only include 0 and 1.

I store it as string format but it may waste the storage since this string only contains 0 and 1. Can any methods store the character in this string with only 1 bit -- just like the binary number?

I should mention that any position in this string can be 0 or 1, so `'000001'` is reasonable.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no "cost-efective" or "special" way to store binary numbers in Neo4j database. Neo4j supports properties of type ([from docs](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/syntax/values/)):

- Integer
- Float
- String
- Boolean
- List of these types

Comment: Thanks! I get it. It seems that it can only store this kind of data as the string type.

Comment: @JackyLiu you are welcome! Yes, I think that string is the appropriate type for you. Also, if this answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this. Thanks!